# C++ Strange Compiler Syntax Error

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I got the following code (do not argue about whether it is meaningful, it is just a minimal example):

```
struct X{
    template <typename T>
    T foo(){ return T(); }
};

template <typename T>
struct Z{
    virtual X bar(){
        bar().foo<int>();
        return X();
    }
};
```

It does not compile on my g++4.6.3. The line `bar().foo<int>();` gives the following error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
```

when I first save the result of bar() in a local variable, then it works, i.e. if I replace `bar().foo<int>()` by

```
        X x = bar();
        x.foo<int>();
```

then it works. If i now declare the local variable `auto` instead of `X`, i.e.:

```
        auto x = bar();
        x.foo<int>();
```

then I receive the same error as before. If I remove the type parameter from class Z (i.e. make it a usual instead of a template class), then it works again.

If I use a classtype like `X` instead of `int` as type parameter for foo, i.e. `foo<X>`, then I receive the following error instead:

```
expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

I am really unable to spot the error here. Please help!

Comment: The code compiler fine in visual studio. In your case I believe gcc has bug :)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis, Comeau C/C++ seems to also compile the original version fine. I, too, think this might just be a bug in GCC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to qualify that the type in question is templatable (this is a work-around for what I think is a bug in GCC, see edit below), i.e.

```
struct X{
    template <typename T>
    T foo(){ return T(); }
};

template <typename T>
struct Z{
    virtual X bar(){
        bar().template foo<int>();
        return X();
    }
};
```

The basic issue has to do with parsing, because explicit template instantiations could be parsed in a number of ways. The interesting bit (I think) is located in 14.2p4, and it is as follows:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a postﬁx-expression or after a
>   *nested-name-speciﬁer* in a *qualiﬁed-id*, and the object or pointer expression of the *postﬁx-expression* or the
>   *nested-name-speciﬁer* in the *qualiﬁed-id* depends on a template parameter (14.6.2) but does not refer to a
>   member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be preﬁxed by the keyword `template`. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

If I'm not gravely mistaken, `Z<T>::bar` *does* depend on a template parameter, but at the same time it does refer to the current instantiation, thus I'm inclined to believe that the standard does not require a qualification like GCC does. When multiple compilers have conflicting results, I tend to side with Comeau, which in this case says that the `template` qualifier is *not necessary*.

Comment: what, why? I have never seen this syntax. In which cases do I have to use it? And why does it result in such strange behaviour when used with `auto`? And why does it work if I remove the type parameter from Z. Z is not involved here at all! Do you have a link to a tutorial that explains all that stuff?

Comment: isn't that line `bar().template foo<int>();` inside `bar` member fn is endless recursion? (though it compiles) or my eyes are popping for nothing?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis, it might be a compiler bug as you noted. I need to look up a thing or two before shifting the blame, though.